# javascript image into byte array

Tags: javascript, image, file-io, yahoo-widgets

Is there a way in javascript for binary file manipulation like C. I'm in a critical situation to create an fliped image. I don't have support for css, canvas, HTML, DOM. But I have to do that with only using javascript. If it allows me to load an image into a byte array I can parse each byte and will create a new image. Is there really a way.....?!

thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript in a browser? How can you not have access to CSS if you have access to JavaScript?

Comment: Actually not in browser. I'm trying in Yahoo! widget. And I'm new to that. So I'm not sure it supports css (actually it supports some styles. but not transform, image-orientation, etc), DOM, canvas.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Yahoo! Widgets it's a different issue. The `Canvas` class allows you to load an image using 'drawImage()', then you can use `scale` with negative values to flip the image. See the reference manual at `Canvas` for more information.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit. Actually I don't have access to the yahoo widget website (URLs having yahoo in them are blocked). And I have only  documents             1.Widget_Creation_Tutorial_1.1              2.YWE_TV_Widget_Developer                       3.YWE_TV_Widget_KONtx                      4.YWE_TV_Widget_QuickStart                     5.YWE_TV_Widget_Install                                  6.YWE_TV_Widget_Media_Player                                         In those documents I can't found what you have mentioned. Can you please help me in this case.

Comment: Hmm... you need to download the documentation or else you won't be able to do much with Yahoo! Widgets. Maybe download it from a different computer or search for it on Google. It's called something like "Konfabulator 4.5 1113 - edit.pdf"

Comment: One more thing. We are not developing for Windows or MAC. We are working for TV widgets. Whether the Canvas thing is possible for us?

Comment: For Canvas, you can have a look at Firefox's documentation. I believe the API is the same - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help friend. Whatever you told was for Windows widget. But I'm working in TV widgets.

Comment: Not sure why they would make the API different for the TV widgets. Might be worth trying Canvas anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", "/images/someing.png", true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function () {
    var data;
    data = new Uint8Array(xhr.response || xhr.mozResponseArrayBuffer);
};
```

This won't work in the current version of IE, so I'm not sure how a widget would handle it.  This allows you to read a png into a byte array though.

Comment: That even not supports XMLHttpRequest. And we dropped that work. So currently I am not interested in it. If possible somebody close this post or tell me how to close it.